# SAP Adapters in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm working on SAP Adapters in IBM Mobilefirst. I have connected to SAP System by using SAP Netweaver Adapter and I'm trying add SAP as a Backend Service but it is failing to fetch the services.

[image: This is the erroe I'm getting]
And while I'm creating SAP Netweaver Adapter by default this is created: `<serviceRootUrl>/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT_2/</serviceRootUrl>`. Is this inbuilt service?

Comment: What is your MobileFirst Platform version? Please add meaningful information to the question, like reproduction steps, any error messages, etc.

Comment: IBM MobileFirst: V 7.0, Error message :Failed to connect to server. HTTP error code: 404,

Comment: Well are you pointing to the right location? Provide fuller server log.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any useful information in the question, such as steps to reproduce.

Per the comments, you say you're getting a 404 error - you need to verify that you are using the correct service URL.

Comment: Now I'm uploading Screen Shot of my error page. Once look into this @Idan Adar